# Nested class in templated class used in templated function syntax error

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes

Suppose I have the following:

```
template<typename T>
    struct Foo
    {
    public:
        class Bar
        {           
        };
    };
```

If I then define the function

```
template <typename T>
void func(Foo<T>::Bar g) { }
```

I get an error:
syntax error: identifier 'Bar'

Why do I get the error and how can I solve it so that I can use the templated function.

Comment: `void func(typename Foo<T>::Bar g) { }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
template <typename T>
void func( typename Foo<T>::Bar g ) { }
```

Otherwise the construction `Foo<T>::Bar` is not considered by the compiler as a type specifier but as an expression.

Comment: How about adding a few words on why the snippet in the question did not work in the first place?